# How to make a script that logs me out of a website?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

[ClockOut button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJFSW.png)

I'd like to make a script that opens chrome, navigates to a website, logs me in, and activates the "ClockOut" button on a website (if it's there) if I forget to clock out at the end of the day. How would I go about doing this? I'm familiar with JS/HTML/Bash but won't tackle this if it's to complicated.

When I navigate to the login portal of the website, www.login.website.com lastpass auto logs me in, so I wouldn't need to input any text, just use the "login" button. I then get loaded into the dashboard, where the "ClockOut" button would be. The page source for the "login" button:

```
<div class="pcty-row-flex">
<div class="pcty-col pcty-padding-top pcty-large-padding-horizontal">
  <button type="submit" class="pcty-button pcty-size-medium pcty-button-full-width pcty-button-full-width-mobile pcty-size-responsive submit-button login-button">Login</button>
</div>
```

The page source for the "ClockOut" button:

```
<section class="js-employeepunch">

  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="webclock js-serverclock-container">
      <div class="title">Clocked In since 12:48 PM</div>
      <div class="clock-seconds js-serverclock-seconds"></div>
      <div class="clock js-serverclock">
        <div class="clock-loader">
          <span class='spinner'></span> Updating...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clock-details">
        <span>CST</span>
        <span class="js-serverclock-period"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-actions js-employeePunchButtons">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="wtNotes">Notes</label>
      <input type="text" id="wtNotes" value="">
    </div>
      <button name="ClockOut" value="Clock Out" class="button  full-width">Clock Out</button>
```

Comment: This works to log me in once I hit the www.login.website.com page: `document.getElementsByClassName("pcty-button pcty-size-medium pcty-button-full-width pcty-button-full-width-mobile pcty-size-responsive submit-button login-button")[0].click();`

Comment: I can open chrome with the console open `start chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tabs https://login.website.com/` but now I need to send the above code to the console somehow, so that it actually clicks the "login" button...